# Dephi: faster way to convert a "dirty" string to a number

Tags: converting, delphi

How can I make this code faster? the string can contain characters such as ", .?#" and possibly others.

```
Const Nums = ['0'..'9'];

function CleanNumber(s: String): Int64;
Var z: Cardinal;
begin
  for z := length(s) downto 1 do
   if not (s[z] in Nums) then Delete(s,z,1);
  if s = '' then
    Result := 0 else
    Result := StrToInt64(s);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically speaking, this function is probably not the single bottleneck of your application, which would mean it takes more than 30% of the total run time. Therefore you don't need to optimize this code for speed, but for correctness and legibility.

If you want to get the maximum speed out of this little function nevertheless, you should look at the implementation of `StrToInt64` and implement the essential from that function yourself. Approximately like this:

```pascal
function CleanNumber(s: String): Int64;
var
  i, num, limit10, limit1: Int64;
begin
  limit10 := MaxInt64 div 10;
  limit1 := MaxInt64 mod 10;

  num := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(s) do
    if (s[i] >= '0') and (s[i] <= '9') then begin
      if num > limit10 then raise EValue();
      if (num = limit10) and (Ord(s[i]) - Ord('0') > limit1) then raise EValue();

      num := 10 * num + Ord(s[i]) - Ord('0');
    end;
  Result := num;
end;
```

I didn't test the code and I'm not sure about the correct syntax for throwing exceptions, but I expect the basic algorithm to work fine. Some test cases:

```pascal
''
'0'
'9'
'100'
'1.0.0'
'1234567890123456789'
'9223372036854775807'
'9223372036854775808' // too large
'-9223372036854775808' // also too large
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa' // => 0
```

Comment: It is a good thinking to get the result without modifying `s`. Although personally I am against reimplementing built-in functions, unless one is buggy or highly inefficient. I am also not sure whether your version is faster, because I believe `StrToInt64` is implemented in assembly and your function has quite a few comparisons.

Comment: Interesting results, 1 million loops with "1234.5678;": 32-bit: Mine = 120-125ms, yours 65-70ms. 64-bit: Mine = 90-95ms, yours... 15-20ms

Comment: Regarding the number of comparisons: the first two comparisons are hopefully optimized by the compiler into a single comparison. The other ones probably don't hurt because branch prediction always predicts them correctly. The two comparisons with `limit10` can also be merged into a single `cmpq` instruction. All in all, I expect the generated machine code to be more efficient than the Delphi source code appears to be.

Answer (score 4):

Don't over use `set`. It is faster when the items are discrete, but slower when the items are continuous. Although, the difference is very small in your case.

The problem here is that you use `delete` repeatedly. Each call moves (copies) a potentially large chuck of characters. This is inefficient because many characters are moved multiple times. For example, `5` in string `1 2 3 4 5` is moved 4 times.

Given that `string` in Delphi is mutable, it is better to copy individual characters:

```
function CleanNumber(s: String): Int64;
Var
  z, l: Cardinal;
begin
  l := 1;
  for z := 1 to length(s) do
    if (s[z] >= '0') and (s[z] <= '9') then
    begin
      s[l] := s[z];
      inc(l);
    end;
  SetLength(s, l - 1);

  if s = '' then
    Result := 0 else
    Result := StrToInt64(s);
end;
```

It can be further improved:

```
function CleanNumber(s: String): Int64;
Var
  z, l: Cardinal;
begin
  l := 1;
  while (l <= length(s)) and (s[l] >= '0') and (s[l] <= '9') do
    inc(l);       // Scan for the first non-numeric char

  for z := l + 1 to length(s) do  // Start from l + 1
    if (s[z] >= '0') and (s[z] <= '9') then
    begin
      s[l] := s[z];
      inc(l);
    end;

  if l = 1 then Result := 0 else
  begin
    SetLength(s, l - 1);
    Result := StrToInt64(s);
  end;
end;
```

Note: code not tested.

Comment: Why did you choose `z` and `l` for the variable names? Especially the assignment `l := 1` is hard to read.

Comment: @Roland Illig: I used `z` because that's what hikari used. I usually use `i` and `j` for loop variables. I used single char `l` instead of my usual `len` because it is more consistent to his/her style. I seldom get confused by `l` and `1` because they are shown in different colors due to the use of theme. I guess I should.